# The lambda function is taking the last parameter for all functions

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote the following thread pool code and after some tests i noticed that the lambda function I wrote will take the last parameter passed to it for all of the executions can someone tell me what is wrong.

```
class Pool{
public: vector<function<void()>> vec;
    int number=0;
    int max_thread=5;

    void add(int i,int res,bloque tableau[N][N],vector<bloque>bloques,int ligne,int colone){
        auto func = [this,i,res,tableau,bloques,ligne,colone](){
            number++;
            calcule(i,res,tableau,bloques,ligne,colone);
            number--;
        };
        vec.push_back(func);
    }
    void start(){
        int counter=0;
        vector<thread> th;
        while(th.size()==counter){
            if(number<max_thread){
                if(vec.size()>counter){
                function<void()> func = vec[counter];
                th.emplace_back(func);
                }}
            counter++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<th.size();i++){
            th[i].join();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Which is the last parameter? You have 7 arguments. Are they all wrong? Where do you call `add`? What is a `bloque` here?

Comment: the array tableau parameter @Useless

Comment: As parameter, `bloque tableau[N][N]` is actually `bloque (*tableau)[N]`, so you copy/capture a pointer (C-arrays are not copiable anyway)